# Problem with ConfigurationStoreOptions while upgrading to Duende IdentityServer 6.0

Tags: duende-identity-server

I have some integration tests that use a real database targetting a ConfigurationDbContext.  When upgrading to Duende IdentityServer 6.0, the constructor for ConfigurationDbContext breaks (only accepts 1 arg instead of 2) because of the DbContext connection pooling feature that was added.

This code breaks:

```
public static ConfigurationDbContext GetConfigurationDbContext()
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConfigurationDbContext");
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    var options = new ConfigurationStoreOptions
    {
        DefaultSchema = Schema.IdSrv
    };
    return new ConfigurationDbContext(builder.Options, options);
}
```

So I changed it to:

```
    return new ConfigurationDbContext(builder.Options);
```

Now I can build, but my tests fail with this error:

`Unable to resolve service for type 'Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Options.ConfigurationStoreOptions'`

How am I supposed to pass the ConfigurationStoreOptions in?  Looking at the code in Github, it looks like it relies on dependency injection.  (Getting the options from services collection).

Answer (score 6):

OK, I figured out my own problem, but I had to hunt and peck around.  It is not listed as a breaking change in the upgrade documentation:

https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/upgrades/v5.2_to_v6.0/

The solution is to upgrade your project to 6.1

```
<PackageReference Include="Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage" Version="6.1.5" />
```

Then you can use this code instead (StoreOptions has been made a public set property)

```
public static ConfigurationDbContext GetConfigurationDbContext()
{
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyIdentity");
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    var options = new ConfigurationStoreOptions
    {
        DefaultSchema = Schema.IdSrv
    };
    var dbContext = new ConfigurationDbContext(builder.Options);
    dbContext.StoreOptions = options;
    return dbContext;
}
```

This will work for ConfigurationDbContext and PersistedGrantDbContext.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to solve the problem. Hope it helps someone.

I had some custom needs so I had earlier created a custom implementation that inherits the original ConfigurationDbContext (and implements an own custom interface). Updating IdentityServer to version 6 broke that base(options, storeOptions).

I had to remove the ConfigurationStoreOptions from the call of the base constructor, but the options can be set in the code block of the constructor and after that everything works for me again:

```
public class ConfigurationStoreContext
    : ConfigurationDbContext<ConfigurationStoreContext>, IConfigurationStoreContext
{
    public ConfigurationStoreContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationStoreContext> options,
        ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions)
        : base(options)
    {
        StoreOptions = storeOptions;
    }
    // custom code here...
}
```